# Limit set of subgroup of Hyperbolic Isometry

Tags: dynamical-systems, geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

When working with subgroup of Klenian groups (or in general just asking for discrete subgroup forgetting about the dimension of Hyperbolic space) the classic definition of limit set $\Lambda(\Gamma)$ is given as the set of accumulation point in the boundary of the orbit $\Gamma(x)$ for a chosen $x\in\mathbb{H}^n$. I have seen it stated in multiple reference but I have never seen it proven explicitly. Now the definition of such a set should not depend on the choice of the $x\in\mathbb{H}^n$. Is it correct to show that by a metric argument such as the following? Fix $x\neq y \in \mathbb{H}^{n},$ as point in Hyperbolic Space (a metric space) I have that $d_{\mathbb{H}^n}(x,y)=d<\infty$ for some real number $d$. Now I consider $\gamma_n(x)\to p\in\partial\mathbb{H}^n.$ Because I am acting via isometry I have that $\gamma_n(y)$ is always at distance $d$ from $\gamma_n(x)$, hence it is in any half-space of $p$ containing $\gamma_n(x).$ But this half-spaces are a system of neighborhoods for $p$, hence the points converge to the same point in the boundary. I hope my argument is, if not correct, at least clear.
Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: No, your argument is unclear (you have to clarify what "half-space of $p$" means. If you simply mean a half space containing $p$ then your claim is wrong.

Comment: Hint: First prove the following: For every $D>0$, each point $p\in \partial {\mathbb H}^n$ admits a neighborhood basis $\{U_i: i\in {\mathbb N}\}$ in ${\mathbb H}^n\cup \partial {\mathbb H}^n$ such that each $V_i=U_i\cap {\mathbb H}^n$ is an open half-space (whose closure contains $p$) and the minimal distance between the hyperplanes bounding $V_i, V_{i+1}$ is $\ge D$.

Comment: Thanks for you help, now I fixed even this point, it is "what I had in mind" but I was not saying it correctly. Appreciated